# pass function in json and execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, observer-pattern

Is there any way that I can pass a function as a json string (conversion with JSON.stringify), send it to another function, parse the json and then execute the function that was in the json? I am using jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rahilwazir/gfbAg/110/)

Basically, you have to be careful with this sort of thing. If you take an extant javascript function, turn it to a string, and eval it, you might run into function redeclaration issues. If you are simply taking a function string from the server and you want to run it, you can do as I did on that jsfiddle:

**Javascript**

```
var myFunc = "function test() {alert('test');}";

$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = new Object();
    data.func = myFunc;
    var jsonVal = $.toJSON(data);
    var newObj = $.evalJSON(jsonVal);
    eval(newObj.func);
    test();
});​
```

Answer (score 62):

Yes, you can. There are tons of ways to do it.

And there is no need to use the "evil" eval function (please yahoogle why it should be avoided) as pointed out here: http://javascript.about.com/library/bleval.htm

```
var tmpFunc = new Function(codeToRun);
tmpFunc();
```

Whether it was JSON at any stage should be irrelevant.

Comment: +1 for "yahoogle". Though isn't Bing more popular than Yahoo these days? Would that be "bingle"? Or the longer phrase Scott Hanselman has used in presentations "Google it on Bing"?

Comment: I agree @GregL, but I coined this phrase some time ago and just don't want to let it go! Using "bingle", "bingoogle"... just doesn't sound right to me. Plus there are plenty of words and proverbs in the English language that refer to outdated things...

Comment: not bad @webnoob but it's too late to change now, 'yahoogle' has gone viral

Comment: I shall make it happen! :)

Comment: very nice! Thanks a lot!

Comment: what of yahingle and ginglehoo

Comment: what am I doing wrong? https://codepen.io/bluebrown/pen/JjjdJaj?editors=0011

Comment: All most enjoyable banter aside, I believe this is the solution to op question. And a nice way to open pandora's box.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, you can convert a function to a string with it's `toString()` method.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/xWHss/) to show converting a function to a string and back to a function:

```
var myfunc = function () {
    alert('It works!');
}

var as_string = myfunc.toString();

as_string = as_string.replace('It works', 'It really works');

var as_func = eval('(' + as_string + ')');

as_func();
```

Comment: Why the extra set of ( )  inside eval ?

Answer (score 5):

take a look at the **JSONfn** plugin.

http://www.eslinstructor.net/jsonfn/

it does exactly what you're asking for.

-Vadim

Answer (score 3):

I created a fork of JSONfn which enables you to stringify and parse objects and their prototypes. In my basic tests it worked fine.

https://github.com/cgarciae/jsonfn

Answer (score 0):

I've found it helpful to use the JavaScript call() function when working with functions in JSON files.

```
var returnData = theJsonData.theFunction.call();
console.log(returnData); // prints any return data
```

I hope that helps anyone that stops by!

Answer (score -11):

No, you cannot do this. Functions cannot be JSON serialized. Instead of converting the object into JSON you could directly pass it to the other function without calling JSON.stringify.

Comment: JSON = JavaScript Object Notation - of course the function can be serialized and passed to and fro. What is an object ? Pretty much anything in JS, functions included.  Get a bit annoyed when someone says "No" when "YES" is the proper answer.  Better to say 'not that I am aware of'.
Bill

Comment: I'd think ten times before saying that smt is not possible in JavaScript :) Hardly can recall even a few "NO"s in JS per se. "HOW" and "WHY NOT" are the most common questions.

Comment: @ArmanMcHitarian You forgot the third-most-common question: "WHY IN THE WORLD DOES IT DO THAT!?"

Comment: As others have pointed out this can be done.