# Javascript - Running a function that is stored in a JSON property

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object, like this:

```
var JSON = 
[
  {
    "cat_function":"(function(){console.log('ITS HAPPENING');})();"
  }
]

JSON[0].cat_function;
```

From my script, I need to load in the function and execute it. Simply calling `JSON[0].cat_function` doesn't work, which I kinda expected; what's the best way to get this to run?

To clarify, this JSON data is coming from a CSV and the function is obviously more complex than just a console.log. The function is stored as a string and there's not much that can be done about it.

Any ideas?

Comment: does the function accept arguments and/or reference external variables?

Comment: It uses `jQuery` (well, `node.js Cheerio`, but close enough) as well as `node.js Request` to parse a webpage and return some values. It's a self-executing function that doesn't accept any arguments.

Comment: This could help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946958/pass-function-in-json-and-execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946958/pass-function-in-json-and-execute)

Comment: @Jascination just to be sure, is the `JSON` used in the browser or in `node.js`?

Comment: @t.niese it's being imported into `Node.js`, this is a backend script and doesn't use the browser at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do

```
var functionCode = JSON[0].cat_function;

var value = eval( functionCode );
```

Anyway, I should warn you that eval is evil so if you can implement another way to import the code it will be better.

Comment: Why evil? This is happening in a `node.js` script, not in the browser if that makes any difference. Not really any other way to load in the code unfortunately!

Comment: Another ones explained it better than me: http://jslinterrors.com/eval-is-evil/
I only wanted to encourage you to use another solution if it were available but in this case I suppose your options are limited.

Comment: @Edorka the `eval` is `evil` is always a little bit misleading, it is not wrong, but it sound always that just `eval` is bad. If you load scripts from external sites (e.g. from `cdn` or via `jsonp` or if it is a node project from a repos) or using `new Function`/`eval` you always have similar issues. Mainly: you need to trust the source because it can execute some code on your page.

Comment: Right said @t.niese, but eval() is one of my try-to-avoid options more because of readability than for security reasons. I was however not talking about nodejs, I've not any experience with it.

Comment: @t.niese Very interesting. The code source is coming directly from me (CSV converted to JSON) so I suppose it should be ok?

Comment: @Edorka Exactly. In nearly every case you can avoid `eval`. I don't use it because it would break on the one hand my code optimization and on the other hand it breaks the _quality layer_ that i have when i use `jslint` or `jshint`.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment/pseudo-code because i currently don't use `node.js` often (so i could be wrong about it).

But what about doing it in a similar way how `jsonp` works in the browser:

**The response you create (loaded data)**

```
handleResponse({
    status : 200,  /* some statuscode like 200, 400 if required */
    data : {
         cat_function : function(){
                            console.log('ITS HAPPENING');
                        },
        some_data : 12345
    }
});
```

**The function that handles the response (in your application code)**

```
 function handleResponse( response ) {
    response.data.cat_function();
 }
```

**The part where you load and execute it (in your application code)**

```
 vm = require('vm');
 yourResponse = functionToLoadTheResponse();
 vm.runInThisContext(yourResponse);
```

Comment: `handleResponse()` is a bit beyond my javascript knowledge, are we talking about an in-browser response?