# AngularJS/Javascript: get JS Functions as JSON/Text and execute

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, function, eval

I'm building and AngularJS app and would like to do the following thing:

I get JS Code with a web service call:

```
{ 
 "script":"function foo(a, b) { c = bar(a,b) $scope.c = c } function bar(a,b) { return a+b }"
}
```

In my AngularJS application I'd like to call foo(a,b) and get the property c in my $scope set to the value computed in the function bar(a,b).

Is this possible? Can the function foo(a,b) access $scope? What if there already exists a function foo() or bar() in my application?

I was already looking at the eval and Function() functionality in JS. But I'm not sure if I can solve my problem like this.

[pass function in json and execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946958/pass-function-in-json-and-execute)

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated :)

Cheers

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at whether you can structure things differently. It's usually a **big red flag** if you're passing around code as text like that, and then eval'ing it. Refactor so you're using proper code if at all possible.

With that out of the way:

> I was already looking at the eval and Function() functionality in JS. But I'm not sure if I can solve my problem like this.

Yes, it can. `eval` works within the scope where you call it (it's a bit magical in that way). So if you `eval` that code within a function, the `foo` and `bar` it creates will only be created within that function, for the duration of the call to that function (unless you keep a reference to them somewhere).

E.g.:

```
function blah($scope) {
    eval(yourString);
}
```

...will create `foo` and `bar` only within that function, and they will have access to the `$scope` argument.

(See note below after e

**Live Example**:

```js
var str = "function foo() { $scope.x = a + b; }";
function bar($scope) {
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
      b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  eval(str);
  foo();
  snippet.log("$scope.x = " + $scope.x);
}
snippet.log("typeof foo === " + typeof foo);
bar({});
snippet.log("typeof foo === " + typeof foo);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Final caveat: Be sure you're only calling `eval` on code **from a trusted source**.

---

It's probably worth noting that this is only true of *direct calls* to `eval`. `eval` is very special; if you call it indirectly, via a variable:

```
var e = eval;
e(yourString);
```

...that **works differently** (specifically, it works at global scope, not in the same scope where you called it). This is why you sometimes see code like `(0,eval)(string);`: That calls `eval` indirectly, making it behave globally rather than locally. (Why not just use `var globalEval = eval;` and then `globalEval(string);`? Some people are really into their l33t stuff like `(0,eval)(...)`. Me, I prefer maintainability, so if I ever needed a global eval [haven't in years], I would go down the `globalEval` route...)

Comment: I agree with TJ here. Somewhere down the line, especially if someone else is editing your code, things like this can throw a major wrench in a project.  I would try and figure out a different way.

Comment: Thank you very much! Especially for the thorough explanation. I haven't had time to use it in my application but created a few snippets and it worked great!

Edit: about the "big red flag": I get this javascript code from a system, which I can't change. But I agree :)