# Access a function as a value in json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rethinkdb

I have a json object

```
"a1":
{
"b1": "val1",
 "b2": "function() {return null}",
 "c1": "{}"
}
```

This function needs to be passed to run a rethink-db query. This function a1.b1 needs to be passed

```
r.db(database).table(table).indexCreate(indexname, a1.b2, a1.c1)
```

When I run the query I get the error  msg: 'Expected type FUNCTION but found DATUM:\n"function() {return null;}"',

Please suggest a fix for this.

Comment: how about adding another line var returnNull = function() {return null}; and update your string to 'returnNull'

Comment: Does this help? http://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/

Comment: using a Set or Map would help

Comment: @Pikamander2 I need to access it from the json object only.

Comment: Functions are not valid JSON. You literally cannot send that over the wire.

Comment: @JaredSmith - It may not be a good idea to do so, but it is possible

Comment: @JaredSmith technically it isn't a function, it's a string. :)

Comment: There are no "good" solutions to this, your only real options are: do something else entirely, or eval. I'd lean toward the side of do something else entirely, meaning, not passing a function expression (is that the right term?) as a string in json.

Comment: True, but you cannot convert it without `eval`/`new Function` etc, making it pretty pointless unless you're *desperate* to get it done at the cost of both performance and security. If you really need to load a function dynamically, you should append a script tag with the `src` attribute set to the file with the function. And yeah, what @KevinB said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one note, you usually shouldn't be sending functions across as JSON, which is the genesis of your problem. However, ignoring that for now, you can do `eval`:

```
r.db(database).table(table).indexCreate(indexname, eval('('+a1.b2+')'), {});
```

Careful with `eval` though. There are security issues, etc.

For some additional ways of evaluating a function from a string, I'd recommend checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946958/pass-function-in-json-and-execute).

Comment: Won't the eval return undefined since the JSON function isn't in parenthesis?