# Send js function through AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I would like to pass "a javascript function" to my backend and I'm using ajax.
This is a short example:

```
var data = { 
    prop: function (e) { alert(e) }
};
ajax.(..., data: data, dataType: "json")...
```

This automatically removes the `prop` from the data because it's a function.

How can I pass this function to my backend with json? Without converting it to a string.

Comment: No way except sending as a text/string

Comment: Question is why? Why do you wish to send a function to backend?

Comment: Following answer might be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946958/pass-function-in-json-and-execute

Comment: By definition JSON is a text format, so *everything* you send as JSON has been converted to a string.

Comment: can't you send the path of file containing js code ? like abc.com/file.js ??

Comment: That's apparently an example of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 5):

You really **don't** want to send a function from the client to the server and execute that function on the server, not without a **lot** of security checks. Think about it for a moment, remembering that you can't trust anything you receive from the client. Separately, the server should already know how to do the things it needs to do; usually what you'd do instead is send a command (a string) telling it to use that function (which it would already have, and thus you could trust).

**But**, if you want to go ahead and do that anyway:

> Without converting to string.

You can't. The only way is to send the function as source code or some other form that can be sent via HTTP, which is ultimately a text-based protocol. So you'd send source code, or you'd compile it to some kind of bytecode of your own devising and then send that (converted to a string, probably Base64 or similar), etc.

As of ES2015, normal functions are required to have a `toString` that takes the form of a valid function declaration or expression, so you could send that string:

```
var dataToSend = {prop: data.prop.toString()};
ajax(..., data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend), dataType: "json")
```

The server would then have to compile that string and execute the result. JavaScript provides a way to do that (`eval`), but again: It's **very dangerous** to execute code received from the client. Doing very dangerous things requires doing a lot of safety checks first.

Answer (score 0):

Current JavaScript versions i.e. < ES2015 doesn't natively support this through the use of functions such as `JSON.stringify()` or similar, although there is a package which you can install if you're using NPM or another package manager for modules.

This package is called [`serialize-javascript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-javascript) which adds a `serialize` function that you can use to convert functions, regexes etc. to a string representation. You could then use `eval` on the server-side.